# Power Automate, Filter Query, Multiple Conditions

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate, flow, powerapp

I am trying to filter my Get Items for multiple conditions. So my first condition on its own works fine but when I add the later 2 conditions, my flow fails.

```
Requester_CostCenter eq 1463 and Specific Automation Type eq 'Testing' and Specific Automation Type eq 'Management Reporting'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to use the "Display name" of list columns in filter query.

However, filter query in Power automate flow works in **internal name** of list columns (same as SharePoint REST API).

So, try using internal name of columns in filter query. You can get internal name of list columns by following this article: [Find the internal name of SharePoint column](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Related Microsoft documentation**: [Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests)

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, how do I find the internal name?

Comment: Check links in my updated answer.

Comment: okay so this seems to work, however when adding an `Or` to my statement it fails.

`Requester_CostCenter eq 1463 and (SpecificAutomationType eq 'Management Reporting' Or SpecificAutomationType eq 'Testing')`

but this works: 

`Requester_CostCenter eq 1463 and SpecificAutomationType eq 'Management Reporting' `

Comment: Try using `or` without capital letters.